# How do i check a bitcoin is valid?

Tags: physical-coins

I have a physical cascius bitcoin from 2012 and would like to check that it is still valid and usable. Please could anyone tell me how i can verify its authenticity without removing the hologram.

Comment: Seems there are several different kinds: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Casascius_physical_bitcoins. They link a tracker at https://casascius.uberbills.com. Some of them appear to have part of the address printed visibly.  You can look that up on a block explorer such as http://blockchain.info.